# Making image in div show on mouseover but in certain way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem, that i am trying to solve 2 days, but i can not get hang of it.
I have 2 divs, both 50% of screen width, and background image inside.
In left div is a guy doing like blast from his hand to half of screen, in right also different guy doing same.
For exp. i want if i mouseover left div that, that blast continue to right div ( image that respresent blast). I used this.

```
$(".left").hover(function(){
$(".left2").stop(true, false).animate({  width: "100%" }, 2000);
}, function() {
$(".left2").stop(true, false).animate({  width: "0%" }, 2000);
});
```

but it makes image scale when it comes. I just want image to unfold left to right. Not to slide it or margin it from somewhere, just to unfold.

If anyone can help me i would really appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unless your _blast_ is not part of the image with the guy, you can't avoid stretching the image.

Comment: please provide your code snippet using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mkwgxu2/)

Notice how I made the blast div `position:absolute` (in fact, I made them all absolute, but only blast *needed* to be) so that I could animate the `left` and `top` properties to create movement.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="leftguy">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" />
</div>
<div id="rightguy">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/240" />
</div>
<div id="blast"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#leftguy').hover(
    function(){
        $('#blast').animate({
            'left' : '300px',
            'top'  : '100px'
        },1500);
    },
    function(){
        //do nothing on hoverOut
    }
);
$('#rightguy').hover(
    function(){
        $('#blast').animate({
            'left' : '0px',
            'top'  : '50px'
        },1500);
    },
    function(){
        //do nothing on hoverOut
    }
);
```

**css:**

```
div{position:absolute;}
#leftguy {}
#rightguy{left:300px;}
#blast{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50px;background:yellow;}
```

Comment: Not really, but my question was not very clear, anyway your answer help me figure it out so thank you very much :)